# Will ᴇɪᴘ86 be implemented for Constantinople?

Tags: eip, metropolis

ᴇɪᴘ86 is [said to be implemented on Metropolis hard fork](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-86.md). Does it means it will be implemented in the Constantinople hard fork planned next October ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [will not be included](https://github.com/ethereum/pm/issues/53). I believe that it will be in Serenity.

Comment: The fact it isn't in the list doesn’t means no but maybe.

Comment: That is the canonical table that each client's team is following in order to prepare for Constantinople. There is activity (nearly) daily. If it is not on this list, the clients are not going to include it in Constantinople.

Comment: That’s why I’m asking the question : because the information is contradictory with what’s merged in the repository (which isn’t updated accordingly).